# Where Does the Storyboard/Layout Info Get Written To?

Tags: ios, swift

I know you can create a screen for an iOS app entirely with code. But when you use the interface builder part of Xcode, where is all of that information going? Is it being written to a file you can view?

Comment: Go into Finder, drill into your project, and open a *.storyboard* file with a text editor. You'll see that it is a XML file, specifically formatted for Xcode to use. as always, when you build your project, virtually everything becomes an executable, including you're storyboard.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

A Storyboard itself is a file contained in your project folder, so you must create a storyboard file in Xcode in advance before using the Storyboard.

**To create a storyboard file:**

- Press Command + N in Xcode ( or choose on File > New > File)

Then you can create a storyboard file, and you can find the file in Xcode Navigator or Finder.

If you want to check the source code of the storyboard file, just open it with text editors.